# Application error with SQL CE 4.0 and ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller, model

I have problem with rebuilding db after Model have been changed/updated. I have three table inside one db file "Posts", "Threads" and "Relations". If i run app and post new thread everything seem fine, I can see thread. If I try to add post on the thread it throws an error saying it cannot find table by name "Thread". If I check "Database Explorer" in Visual Web Developer i can only see table "Posts" which is awkward. Now I read somewhere that db is not created until first use of model (saving?).

My models setup is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Database;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

namespace aspnet_forum.Models
{
    public class Threads
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Author { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
    }

    public class ThreadsDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Threads> Threads { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            DbDatabase.SetInitializer(new MyThreadsDBContextInitializer());

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    public class MyThreadsDBContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ThreadsDBContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ThreadsDBContext dbContext)
        {
            // seed data

            base.Seed(dbContext);
        }
    }
}
```

I also used "DropCreateDatabaseAlways" resulting same error. Posts model is same as Thread with additional field "text" and Posts name where relevant.

Relations model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Database;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

namespace aspnet_forum.Models
{
    public class Relations
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Threads")]
        public int ThreadID { get; set; }
        //public virtual Threads Thread { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Posts")]
        public int PostID { get; set; }
        //public virtual Posts Post { get; set; }
    }

    public class RelationsDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Relations> Relations { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            DbDatabase.SetInitializer(new MyRelationsDBContextInitializer());

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

    }

    public class MyRelationsDBContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<RelationsDBContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(RelationsDBContext dbContext)
        {
            // seed data

            base.Seed(dbContext);
        }
    }
}
```

My Web.Config is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ThreadsDBContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Forum.sdf"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
    <add name="PostsDBContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Forum.sdf"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
    <add name="RelationsDBContext"
           connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Forum.sdf"
           providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

I tried and created all tables and relations by hand and it all works as expected I just don't know if relations will work as expected.

Trying to establish M2M relation between Threads, Posts and Relations table.

PS: there is "EdmMetadata" table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add all three DbSets to the same DbContext. Now that I've read your question again, I see that `Relations` is actually a many-to-one relationship between `Post` and `Thread`. This class can be left out.

This could be your new solution:

```
namespace aspnet_forum.Models
{
    public class Thread
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Author { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Thread")]
        public int ThreadId { get; set; }
        public virtual Thread Thread { get; set; }
    }

    public class ForumContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Thread> Threads { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Thread> Posts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Notice how `Thread` has a collection of `Post`s and how `Post` has a `Thread`. This replaces your `Relationships` class.

Now you also only need one connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ForumContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Forum.sdf"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: In which model class should i put this or do I make new class for this?

Comment: It should be a seperate class. I'll update my answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: I got it working now. Thanks for your help. Only thing left now is fetching all post relevant to Thread Id or Slug. I got it like this: dbForum.Posts.Include(t => t.Thread).GroupBy(t => t.Slug == threadSlug) but I don't know how to fetch this...

Comment: To get all posts for a single thread, you can do either of these: `var posts = dbForum.Posts.Where(p => p.ThreadId == x);` or `var threadWithPosts = dbForum.Threads.Include("Posts").SingleOrDefault(t => t.ID == x);`

Comment: Thanks a bunch now it all works as supposed ;). You have a drink from me.